# How can you subset rows based on the length of factor value of a column?

Tags: r

How do subset the rows that have only length of 2 in this column called "Born?"

Answer (score 0):

We can use `nchar` to create a logical condition.  `nchar` takes a `character` vector, so if the column type is `factor`, convert to `character` with `as.character` and the number of characters

```
df2 <- subset(df1, nchar(as.character(Birthplace)) == 2)
```

Or use `levels`

```
df2 <- subset(df1, nchar(levels(Birthplace)[Birthplace]) == 2)
```

Comment: @MaryJ if it is US states, you can also do `subset(df1, Birthplace %in% state.abb)`